# How to get text of an HTML-Element with Selenium/Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

Unfortunately I did not find any existing solution for my problem on stackoverflow. So, can someone help.

I want to get the text of an html-element. I tried this:

```
var element = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className("credits")).getText();

console.log(element);
```

Unfortunately this did not work so far.

Comment: Can yo post the html that you are trying to get the text from?

Comment: Set `var element = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className("credits")).innerHTML`

Answer (score 14):

Someone posted an answer and deleted it seconds after it...thank you anyway:

For you information, this works fine for me:

```
var textPromise = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className("credits")).getText();
textPromise.then((text) => {
  console.log(text);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead if you are inside an async function:

```
var element = await driver.findElement(webdriver.By.className("credits")).getText();

console.log(element);
```